# How to create a RegEx expression for username that meet the following conditions

Tags: regex

I need to build a regex with following requirement :

- To accept only one special character from `#._-,`
- Accept at least one digits, and at least one alphabet

All that as long as the length is in between 8-100. So far I have come up with the following expression but the problem is that this RegEx can accept any number of special characters as long the length is in between 8 and 100.

```
((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[#\._-])[\w#\._-]{8,100})
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using regex for this? While you *can* use regex to tackle a lot of problems, why not just use whatever programming language you're using to look for those character types? It will likely be a lot faster and easier to read too. If you insist on regex, what language is this? That will help us to know what regex flavor and therefore which features are supported.

Comment: Is there a reason you only want to accept a single 'special' character?

Comment: @dman2306 it is for the form validation in .NET,   You can see on the link how it does the characters matching http://regexr.com/3bhds   . It is one of the requirement .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=[^#._-]*[#._-][^#._-]*$)[\w#.-]{8,100}$
```

should do it.

**Explanation:**

```
(?=        # Assert that the following matches:
 [^#._-]*  # Any number of characters except #._-
 [#._-]    # Exactly one of the characters #._-
 [^#._-]*  # Any number of characters except #._-
 $         # Assert that we've matched until the end of the string.
)
```

Comment: You need to set the multiline flag if you want the regex to match line by line, not the entire text - or delete everything from the test box except the text you're actually trying to match.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I was wondering do I need to have the escape character \ before "." . I know we don't because it worked.  Can you explain me the reason why we don't need a escape character. Also can we change the order for the last part like this (?=[#._-][^#._-]*[^#._-]*$) .

Comment: No, within a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), you don't need to escape the dot; outside of one, you do. And if you change the order, you will only match if the "special" character is the first one in the string.

Comment: Gotcha, I have another question if I want to match the string where I can have letters in lower and upper case, must have one numbers from the 0 to 9 and any of the special characters like !@# but no other special characters and the length of string should be in between 8 and 100, is this a good RegEx, (?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#]{8,100} . Also do i need to use the ^ and $ ?

Comment: Yes, the regex looks OK. Whether you need the anchors depends on the validation method - some methods implicitly apply the regex to the entire string, others accept submatches - it's usually better to be explicity and use `^(?=.*\d)[a-zA-Z0-9!@#]{8,100}$`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried to use it here http://regexr.com/3bhgg but it didn't give me a match, whenever I took out the ^ and $ signs it gave me a match. Do you know why ? How can I know where to put ^ and $ signs? Also what do you mean by the submatches ?

Comment: Well, there are two newlines after the line you're trying to match, and the regex can't match those. By sub-match I mean that without the anchors, the regex would match `abcdde12#` as a submatch of an input string like `"?/§abcdde12#ö&%!"`.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks RegEx guru :)